# Is it possible to target only my home page with a media query?

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries, custom-wordpress-pages

Is it possible to use a media query but limit it so that it only affects my homepage?

I am in the process of setting up a woo-commerce store and all of the site looks OK apart from the homepage when viewed on a mobile device. I've been looking for a solution for days with no success.

If so could you please tell me what code i start off with.
Any assistance greatly appreciated, I am way out of my depth with this.
Paula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use both the media query *and* a way to target the CSS on home.

You need a body class, such as `home` within a media query for the size of the screen you want to target, i.e.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .home .my-selector {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

}
```

WordPres themes usually add a `body` class for the page ID, or the slug of the page, i.e. `home` or `front-page`. Look in the page source inside the `<body>` tag.

It's best to learn how to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site and how to work with and change the CSS and HTML in real time, and then be able to add those changes to your style.css in the theme.

Answer (score 1):

For sure. I think in wordpress you have class `home` in `body` tag, if it's the homepage. So you that inside your class definitions, doesn't matter where the classes are, inside a media query or not.

```
body.home .any-css-selector { styles }
```

You probably have css file:

```
bla {}
blabla {}
@mediaquery mobile {
    body.home .class { styles }
    body.home .another-class { more styles }
    bla {}
    blabla {}
}
```

Comment: thanks jack, so do i edit that in the php file or css?

Comment: That is CSS code. I think you should put it inside the media query used for mobile.

Comment: If it solves your problem, remember to accept answer and upvote.

Comment: so the media query would go in first and then the code youve written above?